# Equivalents to function_exists() and call_user_func() in ASP

Tags: php, asp-classic

Does a function exist in ASP equivalent to `function_exists()` in PHP?

How about an equivalent to `call_user_func()`?

Comment: I think for dynamic function calling, you might have to resort to `eval`! http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/vbscript/13920.asp. As far as I cal see there's no way to determine whether a function exists.

Comment: This stuff is probably all online, so when you ask questions it is worth your taking a few minutes to do a search first - it'll save you some time.

Comment: Halfer – it's online because people asked already – this isn't a bad question, other than the ASP thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this with a trick:

```
public function getFunction(functionName)
    set getFunction = nothing
    on error resume next
    set getFunction = getRef(functionName)
    on error goto 0
end function

dim func : set func = getFunction("myFunction")
if not func is nothing then
    ' call "myFunction"
    func
else
    ' "myFunction" does not exist
end if
```